# What's the most economical way to fill a matrix with random values?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the most economical and elegant code for a simple task: fill an empty matrix with randomly sampled values (here, A, B, or C). For illustration, let's take this matrix:

```
x <- matrix(NA, nrow=8, ncol=4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

To fill it I've used two codes so far, each successfully doing the job. The first uses `sapply`:

```
x[] <- sapply(x, function(i) sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1, replace = F))
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
[4,] "B"  "C"  "A"  "C" 
[5,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "A" 
[6,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "A" 
[7,] "A"  "C"  "C"  "A" 
[8,] "C"  "B"  "B"  "C"
```

while the second is a `for`loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    x[i,] <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 4, replace = T)
   }
x
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "C"  "A"  "C"  "C" 
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B"  "B" 
[3,] "C"  "C"  "A"  "B" 
[4,] "C"  "C"  "A"  "C" 
[5,] "A"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
[6,] "B"  "C"  "A"  "A" 
[7,] "C"  "C"  "B"  "A" 
[8,] "B"  "C"  "B"  "C"
```

I like neither of them as they both look bulky. Is there a better way to get the expected result, that is, is there a shorter and/or more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about assigning it directly?

```
x[] <- sample(LETTERS, length(x), replace = TRUE)

x
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "A"  "H"  "V"  "A" 
#[2,] "X"  "M"  "Y"  "O" 
#[3,] "A"  "W"  "N"  "I" 
#[4,] "H"  "Y"  "Y"  "C" 
#[5,] "W"  "N"  "O"  "P" 
#[6,] "Y"  "H"  "P"  "J" 
#[7,] "I"  "Y"  "N"  "H" 
#[8,] "S"  "F"  "Z"  "I"
```

If you want only include first three `LETTERS` this would work

```
x[] <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], length(x), replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace` without changing the original `matrix`

```
replace(x, TRUE,  sample(LETTERS, length(x), replace = TRUE))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "B"  "O"  "S"  "D" 
#[2,] "N"  "C"  "Q"  "Z" 
#[3,] "X"  "X"  "Z"  "X" 
#[4,] "O"  "G"  "R"  "R" 
#[5,] "L"  "B"  "S"  "U" 
#[6,] "Y"  "I"  "O"  "A" 
#[7,] "L"  "Y"  "P"  "M" 
#[8,] "R"  "X"  "H"  "T"
```

Comment: Do you think this is different from my answer?

Comment: @RonakShah  Yes, you are just updating the original matrix.  Here, it doesn't do it